Taking out the film from the roll can it still work?
Hi all thx in advance for the help.
i retrieved an old olympus camera and tried to shoot some pictures. The film was put in by the dude in a photo lab and the camera seems to work. Pictures taken are counted, camera auto focuses, flash works and zoom as well.
Getting to 36 pictures i tried to take out the film without knowing the rewind button on the botton. The film got all out in a dark dark room. Then i manually rewinded the roll from the head of it. Worked. I m anxious because the film in darkness did not show any imprinting viaible. Is it normal? Also are development labs able to pull out the film that i rewinded too much?
Thx!

"I'm anxious because the film in darkness did not show any imprinting viaible" What do you mean? This sentence is not clear

You say it was "dark dark"...but no room is really that dark in my experience. There's almost always small amounts of light entering somewhere. Film is very sensitive to light (as are our eyes, once they've had time to adjust) and the film can easily be ruined.

About rewinding the film fully into the cassette, that is not an issue. That's what the camera does anyway, and the lab has ways to retrieve the film for development.

The amount of light to see ordinary undeveloped camera film at all with the naked eye, even as the vaguest of vague shadows, is vastly greater than the amount required to totally ruin that portion of the film.  If film is wound around a spool when it is exposed to a relatively dark room, the outer layers will be ruined but the inner layers might be usable.

"Also are development labs able to pull out the film that i rewinded too much?" Yeah, there's a special tool that you insert into the roll and it grabs the end of the film and you pull out the end to be able to run it through the developer. 99% of rolls brought into labs before digital were fully wound into the canister and you just get really good at using the extraction tool really fast.

If the film is completely overexposed or if it can be developed successfully boils down to one thing:
Did you rewind the film in a dark-room or in a dark room? If the room was a lightproof room (a dark-room) with ABSOLUTELY no light in it, the film will be good.
As you said, you could not see any change on the film, I assume that the room was just somewhat dark (By the way, you cannot see the changes of the film until it is developed). In this case the film material is completely overexposed.
If you had opened the camera, immediately closed it again and the used the rewind of the camera, the first images might have been shielded by the film material around it - in your case, the roll is pretty surely gone.
To the second question: You can and should roll back the film completely into the cartridge. The developers are going to open up the cartridge anyways or use a extractor tool, assuming we are talking about common 35mm film cartridges.
The 35mm cartdriges open reasonably easy, when you just smash them on the table, with the protuding knob down. The lid of the other side then just pops off. Note that this is usually done in a lightproof room or in a lightproof bag.
But maybe there are still images?
If you want to make super sure, you can let them develop the negatives ONLY - without ordering prints. You will probably receive an almost black strip back (as in the negative, overexposed areas become very dark). This way you can save yourself the money to order 36 almost completely white sheets of photo paper, while still checking for anything left to recover.

With the naked eye, it is not possible to see any change on film due to (over)exposure. The image is only a latent image until after development.

Thank you for the answer, you got it right it was a very dark room with almost no light coming in. So damage is probable. We will still ask a store to print it and see. Just to be informed the film should already have visible images or marks on it? This is linked to the anxiety i was talking about: we got perplexed when the film that was out of the cartridge did not show any image of any sort (to my untrained eye it looks brown and without any picture imprinted)

As a good first estimate, if you were rewinding the film by sight, it's ruined; if you were rewinding by touch, it might not be.

@yeapnoppy When the shutter fires to take a photo, the image is not visible already on the film. The image only becomes visible on the film after the process of developing the film in chemical photo developer.

@yeapnoppy If you could even see that the film is brown, i.e., you could differentiate colours well, then that room was not dark at all.

@yeapnoppy I worked at a photo development lab in the 1990s. You cannot see any images on film that has not been developed. You can go to a store for development and if there are no usable negatives on the roll, they will not make prints. You'll pay for the development of the roll but not for prints - perhaps 50% - 75% of the total cost for negatives and prints. Where I worked, we never opened rolls. We taped the ends to plastic cards that had sprocket holes on them and then loaded them into a developer machine that pulled the film out of the canisters the same way the camera pulls it.

@yeapnoppy If there was enough light for your eyes to see the film, it is certainly ruined. Film is VERY sensitive to any amount of light. When exposed for 1/100 second through an aperture such as 50mm @ f/2.8 (a hole 18mm wide) it's enough even in dim light. When you open the back of the camera the exposure time is however long the back is open and the film was not protected from light. The aperture is almost 1/infinity, as light from any angle on either side of the film is able to reach it.


...I tried to take out the film without knowing the rewind button on the bottom. The film got all out in a dark dark room. Then i manually rewinded the roll from the head of it. Worked.

It's highly likely if you had enough light to see what you were doing? That the roll of film has been ruined (overexposed to too much light) and won't develop/print properly. You won't know for sure until it's developed, but be prepared to lose the images on that roll.

I'm anxious because the film in darkness did not show any imprinting visible. Is it normal?

Yes. Film looks the same whether it's exposed or not before it's developed.
Photographic images only become visible after the film's been chemically developed. That's kind of the whole point of development. BTW, if your film is color print film? The images  after development will be negatives. Only slide (reversal) film comes out of development looking like the image you took.

Also are development labs able to pull out the film that i rewinded too much?

Yes. The lab can fish it back out if they're not going to simply pop the canister open in a darkroom or changing bag. Also, rewinding until the leader is all the way in the can is what you're supposed to do. In the camera.

Back in the days, we sometimes manually rewinded the film in Camera until we felt the resitance of the leader, took it out & marked down the exosure count on it, if we wanted to swap film. Then we later reinserted the film, put in the fastest exposure time, had the cap on the lens and shielded the lens with additional fabric and advanced the film to the exposure count plus 2 (just to be safe). Crazy workaround in todays context.

@Kai Mattern - Kodak had their "APS" system which included a magnetic stripe with the film.  The stripe recorded exposure and other information, and also allowed the user to swap film mid-roll; using information from the magnetic stripe, a camera could rewind to the leader and then later fast-forward to exactly the first unexposed frame.

@CrashGordon, man I loved my OG Canon ELPH for all the little nice conveniences of APS. No leaders. And clear indicators on the side of the cannister as to what state the roll was in (unexposed, partially exposed, fully exposed, developed) The camera just did everything for you. And no need to protect develop strips of negatives: it was stored in the can. Your prints always came with a contact print with numbered frames. The strip also stored a datetime stamp which would be printed on the back of each print.

@KaiMattern I just did that last week. Ran into a situation that was much better suited for Ektachrome than the less-than-perfect Adox Color Mission.
